# android onQuerySubmit() method search widget giving error

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I do not have much experience with android. I am trying to implement the search widget on android action bar. Search bar appears and I am able to enter the text in it, But when I press the submit button I get this message.

> W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>
> W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface
>   0x7fe63d9c1040, error=EGL_SUCCESS

This is the part of my code

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            System.out.println("In on Query text change");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            System.out.println("In on Query text submit");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

As per the code when I enter the text it prints In on Query text change. But when I press the submit it gives the above error.

EDIT:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    System.out.println("In the menu at main menu");
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();


    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        //searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            System.out.println("In on Query text change");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            System.out.println("In on Query text submit");
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: post your whole code where u initialize searchview

Comment: @Divyesh : I added it in edit section.

Comment: I searched for this error seems related to emulator I suppose, but solutions I found did not worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_view_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Products...");

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                searchView.clearFocus();

                menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).collapseActionView();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }

        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Comment: could please add some explanation.

Comment: you used v7 search view in main_menu.xml?